# Why do my stats momentarily change?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm running a seasonal Crusader with my own variant on the Akkhan Bombardment build. I noticed a strange issue that occurs when I change gear or Kanai's Cube slots, in which my main stats (Toughness, Recovery, and also Thorns (which is important for this build)) go up OR down, and then almost immediately drop back down or go up again. This all happens within a second or 2.

The following stats are all when switching **ONE** Kanai's Cube modification at a time, and are shortened for this post, but the numbers are all the same anyway:

**Toughness**: 47m > 22m > 33m > 47m

**Recovery**: 4.4m >  3.2m > 4.4m

**Thorns**: 222k > 316k > 253k (this is with a Thorns based item, so the end result will be higher)

Why do these stat changes occur? Is it calculating something else based on maybe the Ring of Royal Grandeur, which reduces set cost by 1? It's kind of frustrating to see, as I'd love for my thorns to be at 316k, but it drops down quite a lot almost immediately.

EDIT: Sets in use:

5 Pieces of Akkhan

2 Pieces of Captain Crimson

2 Pieces of Invoker

Comment: Are you using Endless Walk set by any chance?

Comment: edited, nope :)

Comment: what amulet/rings (besides the rorg)?

Comment: Convention of Elements and Justice Lantern (increases damage reduction based on my block chance)

Comment: CoE affects thorns damage: afaik thorns damage is physical, and CoE buffs physical during one of its phases. But it should be single spike of up to +200% damage, I cannot figure how it could result in 3 different values

Comment: True, CoE does affect physical damage, but I know that the elemental buffs from amulets/rings/whatever don't really have a *visible* effect on stats, as far as I've seen anyway, while still adding more damage when attacking.

Comment: My best guess is some weird way the game recalculates all your buffs and stuff after a change.  Why it would bump your thorns higher than normal I have no clue.